# How to enable dark mode UI effect always for my iOS app even pre ios 13

Tags: ios, ios-darkmode

My iOS app looks great in dark mode. 
I googled around but I couldn't find. How to leave the Dark mode effect on my app alone even though device is in light mode.

I don't know how to do it before iOS 13.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding this line of code in app delegate.(For whole app level)

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
}
```

Other option is to specify that mode in plist file

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Dark</string>
```

Comment: That's great. But I would like this to happen with pre iOS 13 as well.Any ideas please